# Will my Lenovo Mahobay motherboard work with a DDR3 1866MHz RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility, lock, lenovo-desktop-computer

I have a Lenovo Mahobay motherboard with 2 RAM slots which support DDR3 memories, and I currently have a DDR3 665Mhz RAM in it and i want to upgrade it. I also have an Intel i7-3770 CPU in it. I found a 2x8 GB DDR3 1866MHz RAM on the internet, but I read on this forum that it may not work, or if will work, it will lock it down to 1600MHz. I'm not an expert in this. Any advice?

Comment: Model of Lenovo Desktop?

Comment: If it worked, it would be at 665MHz. All RAM cards need to work at the same frequency.

Comment: @eventHandler I would replace those RAMs for 2x8GB RAMs, not adding to them.

Comment: @Moab It is a Lenovo ThinkCentre M series, but it is probably only the case, the components are likely different because it is a used office pc. If you're curious of any hardware in it, i can give you the name of it.